# Question about probability?

Tags: probability

A boy and his 2 girlfriends A and B. But he don't know which girl that he love more. He randomly visit his 2 girlfriends: go to the bus stop, if he see the bus that have route to girl A, he'll get this bus and visit A, and similarity for B if he see bus have route to girl B. Both 2 routes have bus every 10 minutes. After a long time, he realize that the times he visit A is triple the times he visit B. Can you explain this problem by probability ? thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bus A comes: |----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|...
Bus B comes: ----|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------...
Boy arrives   BBBBAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAA...
```

If the boy arrives at a time window "AA...A", he will gets bus $A$.
Otherwise he gets bus $B$. 
Let $W_{A}$ be the even the boy arrives during the $AAA..A$ window,
and similarly $W_{B}$ for $B$.

Let $Pr(W_{A})$ be the probability that the boy arrives during a time window for $A$.
Then, we know:
$$
Pr(W_{A}) 
= 3 \times 
Pr(W_{B}).
$$
But 
$$
Pr(W_{A}) + Pr(W_{B}) =1
$$
because one of the two events will happen no matter what.
We conclude that
$$
Pr(W_{A}) =\frac{3}{4} 
\quad\text{and} \quad
Pr(W_{B}) =\frac{1}{4}.
$$

If we assume that the boy arrives uniformly at random at some point in the time line, then we can also say something about the bus schedule.
That is because the probability that the boy arrives in a time window for $A$ is proportional to the size $T_{A}$ of that time window.
Hence,
$$
T_{A}
= 3 \times 
T_{B}.
$$
But 
$$
T_{A} + T_{B} =10 \text{ minutes}.
$$
We conclude that
$
T_{A} = 7.5$ minutes and $T_{B} = 2.5$ minutes.
Hence bus $B$ comes $2.5$ minutes after bus $A$ comes and leaves.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the buses arrive and leave the bus stop instantaneously. Bus A and bus B each leave the bus stop every 10 minutes, but offset by $10/4=2.5$ minutes. Specifically, $2.5$ minutes after bus A leaves, bus B arrives/leaves, and then after $7.5$ more minutes, bus A arrives/leaves, and so on.

If the guy arrives in one of the 2.5-minute windows, he will take bus B, and if the guy arrives in one of the 7.5-minute windows, he will take bus A. Assuming he arrives at the bus stop at any time with uniform probability, he will take bus A with probability $3/4$.